# Javascript Bluetooth API Not Finding My Device

Tags: javascript, bluetooth

I'm trying to find my device listed under the bluetooth options when I am trying to use the Javascript Bluetooth API, but my device `John's iPhone` is not showing up for me to pair with. Really new at this, so was hoping to get some help on this issue.

I've linked the code below. All I see is null and unknown devices that fail to connect.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  onButtonClick();
});

function onButtonClick() {
  const options = {
    "acceptAllDevices": true
  }

  navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(options)
    .then(device => {
      log('> Name:             ' + device.name);
      log('> Id:               ' + device.id);
      log('> Connected:        ' + device.gatt.connected);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      log('Argh! ' + error);
    });

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you have Bluetooth turned on on both devices.

If your devices are already paired, put the target one (in your case `John's iPhone`) in pairing mode. Even though it's paired, it still needs to "pair" with the browser.

After that, if it still doesn't show, in Chromium-based browsers (such as Chrome or Edge) navigate to `about://bluetooth-internals#devices`. You should see a table with all nearby Bluetooth devices in pairing mode on this page. If nothing shows, you might need to click `Start Scan` in the top right corner of the page. Locate your Bluetooth device (in your case it will have `John's iPhone` in the `Name` column (first column)) in this table and then click `Inspect` in the last column.

Once you've done this, your device should show in the browser-based Bluetooth pairing dialog box as the first item in the list the next time you call `requestDevice`.

Answer (score 0):

Its `console.log()` instead of `log()`

Example:

```
...
  navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(options)
.then(device => {
  console.log('> Name:             ' + device.name);
  console.log('> Id:               ' + device.id);
  console.log('> Connected:        ' + device.gatt.connected);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('Argh! ' + error);
...
```

Comment: This is just incorrect; it's possible and likely they have an implementation of log(). This does not answer the question.

Comment: I just run your code and this is the error I got, fixed it and it works for me, maybe its the browser? i used Chrome

Comment: This doesn't apply; read my above comment. There is more code not shown

Comment: Yeah, not if you have `const { log } = console;` somewhere. He would have hit his `catch` handler if `log` was `undefined`.